# Proof that $K(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$ is a kernel

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, kernel-trick

I cannot find a proof that $K(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ is a Kernel for any real valued function $f$ and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Obviously it is symmetric but can someone prove that it is positive semidefinite?

My only idea is plugging the function into the defintion of semi-definiteness:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nK(x_i, x_j)c_ic_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nf(x_i)f(x_j)c_ic_j\overset{?}{<}0$$

Since $f$ can also take negative values I do not see why the sum should be non-negative.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nK(x_i, x_j)c_ic_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nf(x_i)f(x_j)c_ic_j = (\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)c_i)^2 \geq 0$

Comment: That doesn't really help because I now have to show that $K(x,y)$ can be written as an inner product, hence that the double sum is positive-definite.

Comment: I edited answer accordingly

Comment: How did you combine the two sums to obtain the last squared term?

Comment: @exan you can split the double sums to two sums, which are equal.