# Prove that $k(x,y) = f(x)\tilde{k}(x,y)f(y)$ is a valid kernel

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

Given that $f: \chi \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, prove that $k(x,y) = f(x)\tilde{k}(x,y)f(y)$ is a valid kernel, using only the fact that addition and multiplication yields valid kernels.

My approach was to prove that $f(x)f(y)$ is a valid kernel and then use the fact that multiplication yields $f(x)\tilde{k}(x,y)f(y)$, but I'm not entirely sure if this is the right approach. I was also looking at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322220/proof-that-kx-y-fxfy-is-a-kernel) question and was confused how this answer proves that $f(x)f(y)$ yields a valid kernel, since it seems like $y$ isn't included in the proof.

Could someone provide an explanation of this proof in that post / point me in the right direction for proving that $f(x)\tilde{k}(x,y)f(y)$ is a valid kernel?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  A kernel $K(x, y)$ on $\mathcal{X}$ is positive when the $n \times n$ matrix $[K(x_i,\, x_j)]_{i,j}$ is semi-definite positive for any choice of $n$ elements  $x_i$ in $\mathcal{X}$ , as was proved in the answer to the cited question.